# Replace EntityFramework Query with ORM to gain performance - need to support iqueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, dapper, iqueryable

We have some of the dashboards in application which has 10,000s of records, of course we have pagination - but EF is very poor in terms of performance and all those Get Queries for Bulk retrieval are very slow.

I was looking into few options to replace those queries with either Dapper or ORMLite kind of Micro-ORM but unfortunately, they do not support  iqueryable  which is a must have for our dashboards/grids because we have lots of things going on like, filtering-search-sort etc.

The question i would like to put forward is, is there anyone who has come across similar situation? What path did you opt for?

Comment: Well you can rule dapper out - it doesn't suppot `IQueryable<T>`; have you looked at tools like LLBLGenPo? have you tried the most recent versions of EF?

Comment: Yes, we are using EF 6.0+ -  i have not looked into  LLBLGenPo, let me look into that!

Comment: Can you give us an example of slow LINQ query? Most of the time, replacing EF by another tool will not improve anything if you still want IQueryable support. Dashboards with only 10,000 records are nothing, even a few millions is not a lot so is the issue really cause because of Entity Framework? There is a lot of options and third party library to improve performance like Query Cache, Include Optimized, Include Filtering, etc..I think the first step before thinking to switch to another ORM supporting "IQueryable" will be to make sure EF cannot do the job right.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you disable tracking in your EF queries (`AsNoTracking()`), this should give you first boost.

Then, tune the database, reindex, move to a faster machine etc.

If things are still too slow, consider trying the old good Linq2SQL, it is faster at materializing.

If still not satisfied, forget the `IQueryable`, have a parametrized view/stored proc and use Dapper to call the server with all necessary params.

Comment: Yes, the first thing i tried was to apply AsNoTracking() on Dashboard queries. Other parts of system need to have tracking as we use EF context-change (changeTracker) to keep track of changed Entities for Auditing purpose, however in the case of dashboards which are most of them View Only, we don't need tracking - after all efforts, conclusion is we need to get rid of EF for heavy retrieve operations